# Авторизация в ВК без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: авторизация, javascript, вконтакте, php

```
    <!-- Put this script tag to the <head> of your page -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?105"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  VK.init({apiId: 3154115});
</script>

<!-- Put this div tag to the place, where Auth block will be -->
<div id="vk_auth"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Auth("vk_auth", {width: "200px", authUrl: vk.php});
</script>
```

При регистрации меня перебрасывает на php страницу. 
Обычный preventDefault не спасает, и страница все равно загружается. Как можно получить параметры от страницы vk.php?

Или подскажите хотя бы, как открыть этот файл (vk.php) в другой вкладке? Куда вставить target_blank?

Answer (score 1):

target тут не куда нельзя вставить, это не ссылка. А AJAX не пробовали? Или скрытые IFrame?
Вот, почитайте еще пару статеек:
[тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/188102/) и [тут](http://сигачев.рф/posts/31). А вообще сразу обращайтесь [сюда](http://bit.ly/18nZbq5), если что.

Comment: аяксом как получить? Обычный preventDefault не спасает